# HTTP Error 503 after importing IIS content using web deploy

Tags: iis, webdeploy

I have recently used the Microsoft Web Deploy utility to migrate my entire IIS content. The destination server was new with nothing already in the IIS. After I imported the content to the new server I tried to navigate to the default site using local host and got the "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." error. 
I went to the basic settings and tried the Test Settings... I got an error on the Authorization test "Cannot verify Access to path (c:\inetpub\wwwroot). The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with build-in account... "

as mentioned in the details of that error I went and checked the IUSERS permission to access the physical path and it all seem ok.

in the app pools, the Default Web Site seem to stop after each time I try and browse to it. All other entries in the app pools are started.

I tried a few suggestions but nothing seem to work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I noticed that in the event log I had a repeat of "The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load" errors. 
I reinstalled the rewrite from 
[http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9722532(x64)](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9722532)

[http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9722533 (x86)](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9722533)

Once installed and recycle my IIS error is gone and sites are showing as expected.

Thanks,